# How to allow getUserMedia on a ionic project with crosswalk

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

When I run my ionic app with crosswalk, and try open the camera through the  getUserMedia api. I get the PermissionDenied error

[image: getUserMedia permissionDenied]

How to allow the access to camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve as follows:

**1º** Simply using pure cordova, without ionic or CCA.

**2º** Adding the crosswalk plugin:

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Repository page: https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

**3º** And in the AndroidManifest.xml add the line:

> < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

See more permissions at:
https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/manifest/permissions.html

The importance of the CSP rules still remain, as ***QuickFix*** said.

> :media-src: 'self' mediastream:

Comment: Adding 'blob:' to the Content-Security-Policy media-src works in Chrome: `media-src * blob:`

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured content secutity policy in your html file? (please discard this answer if you're not using cordova 5 with plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist)

I think that in order to use getUserMedia in cordova, you have to add the following string in your CSP meta tag :

```
media-src: 'self' mediastream:
```

(csp configuration borrowed from [this page](https://github.com/jbuck/csp-and-gum))

More info about the cordova-plugin-whitelist [there](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#user-content-content-security-policy) and CSP doc [there](http://content-security-policy.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. It seems that in the ionic, It is locked in another way.
But with pure cordova, this 'CSP' directive is right.

Comment: As ionic is based on angular, have you tried adding angular-csp.css ? ( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp )